# Getting previous UITableViewCell in loading of next cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So, this is weird.

I have a UITableView that loads cells in from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I'd like to know the state of the previous cell before properly loading the current cell, so I load in the previously created cell with `CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 inSection:indexPath.section]];` but I am always getting nil.

I'm not sure what's going on as this process seems pretty simple - does the table view not save the cell on each run of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I think (not sure) you can't access the cells until  reloadData has finished.

Comment: I suspected that might be happening. If that is indeed the case - how could I approach setting the current state of a cell based on the state of a previous cell?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to access the state of the previus cell? why you want to access the state of the cell instead of accessing the data passed to your previous cell?

Comment: How do you set the state of the first cell? - can't you use the same method to set the second one?

Comment: Javier: Sorry, I meant the data passed to the previous cell - but doing so, I need access to the cell.

Comment: Wezly: I have a special case for the 1st cell (it should always be enabled, for example). The 2nd cell should only be enabled if the 1st cell has text. 3rd cell should only be enabled if the 2nd cell has text etc.

Comment: You don't need access to the cell to do this, you should be accessing the data source, which should know what data has been passed to the previous cell.

Comment: rdelmar: That's... actually a smart approach. Don't know why I didn't think of that. That should fix it - cheers mate.